# Vimrc for different gnome-terminal profile?

Tags: gnome-terminal, vimrc

I want to load different VIM color schemes for different gnome-terminal profiles. It's indeed two questions:

1. How to know the active profile name in a gnome-terminal session?
2. How to test with environ variables in vimrc scripts?